# Creating Custom trained models in google cloud speech to text

Tags: google-cloud-speech

In my project, I am using google cloud speech to text to convert Georgian to text in real time. I aim to use this for the translation of medical terms. But medical models are currently unavailable for the Georgian language in google cloud speech to text. Can custom models be created in google cloud speech to text to do it instead?